Switch to old Google OAuth design
I'm having difficulties passing OAuth consent screen verification in Google Console. The reviewer keeps telling the OAuth screen incorrectly shows the app name and scopes requested. I suppose that happens because Google's reviewer expects older OAuth screen design, while Google seemed to switch to the newer design.
This is a screenshot of the OAuth form, expected by Google's review team:

And this is a screen I get when calling requestAccessToken function.

While the screens are similar, it's obviously a different design and the Third Party Data Safety Team constantly complaints that my video doesn't show OAuth screen.
I tried:

Highlighted OAuth page address, to confirm it's actual Google OAuth page,
Showed my JS code that invokes the OAuth page.

Unfortunately, without success. It seems that they need me to present the OAuth for in old design to pass the review.
Do you have any ideas on how to launch the Google OAuth form in previous design shown on the first screenshot?
If necessary, here is a link to the video showing the OAuth screens the app uses: https://youtu.be/ye7evVeidfI

I think the issue is likely with your app name.  wartermarkly.com is a website you need an app name not a website name.      You can not change the auth screen this is designed by google.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you for the suggestion. The new OAuth form shows website address instead of specified app name and ignores the app name. I checked the client_id param is correct, sent screenshots to Google and they said to use „ An accurate and up-to-date application name”. So I changed the app name to what the OAuth form displays: „watermarkly.com”.

After about 20 messages, the Google team finally sent me a screenshot of the OAuth screen they test and it turned out they have been testing a different app.
